# Identic lines in each action - should I let them this way or not? - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a controller which has actions for inserting in the database, updating, deleting and some others, but almost all of the actions contain in them this lines:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(); 
$friend = $em->getRepository('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend')->find($id);
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Is this OK, or it's code duplication? I tried to make a property called `$em` and to have a constructor like this:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
}
```

but it didn't work. As for the queries especially the one with the `$id` parameter, I don't even know how to separate them in one place, so each action to be able to use them. One way is a function, but is there sense in a function like this? And if yes what should it return? An array?

Please advise me for the optimal way!

Comment: S2.1 now has a getUser() method in their base controller so that line at least can be simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
private $em;
private $friend;
private $user;

private function init($id==null) {
    $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(); 
    $this->friend = $id?$this->em->getRepository('EMMyFriendsBundle:Friend')->find($id):null;
    $this->user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
}
```

Then you can call in your actions

```
$this->init($id);
```

or

```
$this->init();
```

And you will have

```
$this->em;
$this->friend;
$this->user;
```

available. Note that I allowed for the $id parameter not to be set, as I guess that in some actions you will not have it.

If you want this init function to be available in different controllers, create a base controller and extend from it, as suggested in another answer.

Comment: This may work but it's definitly not a flexible solution because the init function is way more to coupled to what wants to do ONE action of his controller. It'll end up with one init() method per action which will be duplicated code. See my answer.

Comment: No, in the question it says: "almost all of the actions contain in them this lines", so it will be just one init() function for all (or almost all) the actions. Your answer is fine, but if you have a getRepository method, a getFriend method and a getUser method, you´ll end up calling all three in every action, so an init() method may be good after all

Comment: Is it a good idea to create a controller with getRepository, getFriend and getUser methods, and then depending on each Controller to create for it an init function? From example for the Friend controller the init function to call in itself getRepository and getFriend methods from the extended controller.

Comment: Some methods like getRepository or getUser may be used in many different controllers, so it makes sense to have them in a base controller class. Others like getFriend are probably only used in one specific controller, so it is best to define it there. You can have an init function in your base controller which calls all the common initalitiation stuff and then have init methods in each controller which call the parent init() and then do their particular stuff

Comment: And one last question - how to avoid the need to write the full path before calling each method of the created controller? It has namespace `namespace EM\MyFriendsBundle\Controller;` and I write `use EM\MyFriendsBundle\Controller\Controller;` in the beginnig of the class where I want to use it, but the methods are not defined, if I don't call them this way: `$user = \EM\MyFriendsBundle\Controller\Controller::getCurrentUser();`

Comment: You have to extend that class instead of the symfony controller class. For example at the beginning of the file say use use EM\MyFriendsBundle\Controller\Controller as BaseController; and then your particular controller should extend BaseController;

Comment: I will post my code [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16643/discussion-between-faery-and-carlos-granados) to not write many comments.

Answer (score 3):

What I do, for Symfony2, in the controllers to avoid code duplication is creating a class called `Controller.php` in which I put the function I often use.

For example :

```
<?php

namespace YourProject\Bundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller as BaseController;

/**
 * Base Controller for xxBundle
 */
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Get repository
     *
     * @param string $class class
     *
     * @return Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
     */
    protected function getRepository($class)
    {
        return $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository($class);
    }

    /**
     * Set flash
     *
     * @param string $type type
     * @param string $text text
     */
    protected function setFlash($type, $text)
    {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add($type, $text);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the pager
     *
     * @param integer        $page    Page
     * @param integer        $perPage Max per page
     * @param Doctrine_Query $query   Query
     *
     * @return \Pagination
     */
    public function getPager($page = 1, $perPage = 10, $query = null)
    {
        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');

        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $query,
            $this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1),
            $perPage
        );

        return $pagination;
    }
```

After creating this controller, you need to make your apps controller `extends` the controller you've created.

That way, you avoid duplicated code and alias for popular method.

Comment: Thank you very much for the wonderful answer and example! If there was a way, I would accept your answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for probably is param converter which maps action param to object directly.

Here is description and some examples:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

**edit:**

Some more info in an interesting article:

http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2012/08/04/multiparamconverter-for-symfony2/

Answer (score 1):

If you have that code only in a couple of controllers you can wrap that code into a protected method for both.

If you think that you can reuse that code in more parts of your application then you should start to think if you need write a validator, use a service or another kind of design